# Exception caught by widgets library (setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.)

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket, charts

I have this application in flutter that calling a price data using a websocket api in a form of a line chart using flutter widget.

Here is the dart file name, chart.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';

const String apiKey =
    "apikey";

class Chart extends StatefulWidget {
  const Chart({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChartState createState() => _ChartState();
}

class _ChartState extends State<Chart> {
  late final IOWebSocketChannel channel;
  List<DataPoint> chartData = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
      'wss://streamer.cryptocompare.com/v2?api_key=$apiKey',
    );
    subscribeToStream();
  }

  void subscribeToStream() {
    final subRequest = {
      "action": "SubAdd",
      "subs": ["2~Coinbase~BTC~USD"]
    };
    final subRequestJson = jsonEncode(subRequest);
    channel.sink.add(subRequestJson);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    channel.sink.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void updateChartData(num price) {
    setState(() {
      chartData.add(DataPoint(DateTime.now().toString(), price.toDouble()));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: channel.stream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final message = snapshot.data;
              print("Received from Cryptocompare: $message");

              final decodedMessage = jsonDecode(message.toString());
              final messageType = decodedMessage['TYPE'];

              if (messageType == '2') {
                decodedMessage.forEach((key, value) {
                  if (key == 'PRICE') {
                    num price = decodedMessage['PRICE'];
                    updateChartData(price);
                    print('Price: $price');
                  }
                });
              }
            }

            return SfCartesianChart(
              primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(),
              primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
                numberFormat: NumberFormat('#.5'), // Display one decimal place
              ),
              series: <LineSeries<DataPoint, String>>[
                LineSeries<DataPoint, String>(
                  dataSource: chartData,
                  xValueMapper: (DataPoint data, _) => data.x,
                  yValueMapper: (DataPoint data, _) => data.y,
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DataPoint {
  final String x;
  final double y;

  DataPoint(this.x, this.y);
}
```

When I try to run it, it shows the chart and the price on the line chart fine at first and then when the data is updated i got an error regarding the : Exception Caught By Widgets Library error in Flutter,
and then it updates again, it shows the chart fine and it keep show the chart and then the error and it goes on each data update.

here is the full error:

```
setState() or markNeedsBuild()
called during build.
This Chart widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuildO was called
Was:
Chart
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
StreamBuilder<dynamic>
See also: https://flutter. dev/ docs/testing/errors
```

If you can help, It is much appreciated! You can ask me any question in the comment.

Comment: Remove setState from updateChartData()

Comment: it worked now! thank you so much for you help. now i can move on :):)

Comment: If this is the solution for your problem then write an answer and mark it as solved.

Comment: Have added answer. Please mark it as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to do setState in your `updateChartData` function as you are already getting updated data in the build function so your chart UI will build with the updated data points from your `chartData[]`.

Change this

```
 void updateChartData(num price) {
    setState(() {
      chartData.add(DataPoint(DateTime.now().toString(), price.toDouble()));
    });
  }
```

to this

```
 void updateChartData(num price) {
     chartData.add(DataPoint(DateTime.now().toString(), price.toDouble()));
  }
```